# Prove that functional set is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
$p_1(f)=f(0), p_2(f)=f'(0),p_3(f)=f(1)$ are linear functionals 
$f \in V=\Bbb R[X]_{\le 2}$
Prove that $p_1,p_2,p_3$ is a basis for $V^*$

**What I did:**
So I understand I need to prove that $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are linearly independent so I need to show:
$a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3=0 \Rightarrow a_1p_1(f)+a_2p_2(f)+a_3p_3(f)=0$$
 \Rightarrow a_1f(0)+a_2f'(0)+a_3f(1)=0$
so I need to show that f(0), f'(0) and f(1) are linearly independent.

If f is of degree 2 then if $f(1)=f(0)$ then $f=x^2-x$ and then $f'(0)=-1$ and then the solution must be trivial.

If f is of degree 0 then the solution may not be trivial (for example $f(0)=f(1)=c),f'(0)=0$.

If f is of degree 1 then $f=cx: f'(0)=c ,f(1)\ne f(0)$ Can I now say that the only a's for that are zeros? I can find for example $f(x)=3x$ where $f(0)=0, f(1)=3,f'(0)=3$ and this will not be linearly independent. This is where I'm stuck...

Comment: The notation is a bit confusion. You should write $p_1(f) = f(0)$ instead of $p_1 = f(0)$.

Comment: Two linear functionals $p$ and $q$ are equal if $p(f) = q(f)$ **for all** $f \in V$.

Comment: I stand corrected. fixed. :-)

Comment: But if q=0, then q(0)=0, isn't it?

Comment: I take back my statement :P Let me check it.

Comment: You can't show that $f(0)$, $f'(0)$ and $f(1)$ are linearly independent, and it's not your goal. You have to *assume* $a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3=0$ and prove that $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, which is a very different thing.

Comment: Okay, Any hints on doing that in another way? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll discuss two (equivalent) methods. The first one is a bit more direct.

To show that $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ are linearly independent, suppose
$$
a_1p_1 + a_2p_2 + a_3p_3 = 0.
$$
This means
$$
a_1p_1(f) + a_2p_2(f) + a_3p_3(f) = 0
$$
for all $f \in V$.
If $f = 1$, then $p_1(f) = 1$, $p_2(f) = 0$ and $p_3(f) = 1$, so
$$
a_1 + a_3 = 0.
$$
If $f = x$, then $p_1(f) = 0$, $p_2(f) = 1$ and $p_3(f) = 1$, so
$$
a_2 + a_3 = 0.
$$
If $f = x^2$, then $p_1(f) = 0$, $p_2(f) = 0$ and $p_3(f) = 1$, so
$$
a_3 = 0.
$$
We now have a system of $3$ equations with $3$ unknowns.
Since this system is non-singular (the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is non-singular), $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$. By dimension counting, $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ span $V^*$.

Another method is via the isomorphism to the known vector space $\mathbb R^3$ and its corresponding space of functionals. Define $\varphi:\mathbb R^3 \to V$ by
$$
\varphi(a_1e_1 + a_2e_2 + a_3e_3) = a_1 + a_2x + a_3x^2
$$
where $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$.
$\varphi$ induces a map $\varphi^*:V^* \to (\mathbb R^3)^*$ defined by $\varphi^*(f) = f \circ \varphi$.
We will let $\mathbb R^3$ be the space of column vectors and $(\mathbb R^3)^*$ be the space of row vectors. They act by the conventional matrix multiplication.
Then, $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ are mapped by $\varphi^*$ to
\begin{align*}
\varphi^*(p_1) & =
\begin{pmatrix}p_1(1) & p_1(x) & p_1(x^2)\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
\varphi^*(p_2) & =
\begin{pmatrix}p_2(1) & p_2(x) & p_2(x^2)\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
\varphi^*(p_3) & =
\begin{pmatrix}p_3(1) & p_3(x) & p_3(x^2)\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
These three elements are linearly independent (the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is non-singular), so they form a basis of $(\mathbb R^3)^*$. Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, $\varphi^*$ is also an isomorphism.

Comment: When you've proved that $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ are linearly independent, you're done, because you know that $\dim V=3$, so also $\dim V^*=3$.

Comment: That's true. I just assumed too little :P Maybe I should shorten it and make it more concise.

Comment: You could also remark that you're evaluating the linear combination $a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3$ on a basis of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does seem like a lot more to write but I'll do that.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded solution! But isn't p2(x^2)=0 and not 2?

Comment: @user1685224 You are right. I wrote it wrong. The second time below was write :P